# Passing class type in a variable

Tags: ios, swift

In swift 2.0 is there a way to pass the type of the class in a variable so that I can later use it for checking if a object type 'is' that class type. 
Better explained thru following example :

```
class Base {..}
class Derived : Base {..}
var obj: Base = Derived()
if obj is Derived {
   print("obj is Derived type")
}
```

This is fine. But I want to be ability to store the class type 'Derived' in a variable something like this :

```
let classType = Derived  // Of course this will give compile error
```

And use it later to check the type of an object :

```
if obj is classType {..}
```

The closest I came to dealing with saving the Class type is:

```
let classType = Derived.self
```

This says the classType is of type 'Derived.Type', but you can't really use that for checking the object type as below :

```
if obj is classType {..blah.. } // Compile error.'Use of undeclared type 'classType'
```

I hope you are getting my point. I'm trying to store the class type in a variable and later use that to check if the object belongs to that type. 
Is there a way to do it. 
I looked at similar forums on stack overflow but nothing which came close to answering this.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
    class Base {}
    class Derived : Base {}
    var obj: Base = Derived()
    if obj.dynamicType === Derived.self {
        print("obj is Derived type")
    }
```

Comment: looks like obj.dynamicType is not supported in newer version of swift 2.0

Comment: @Feru Really? Well _that_ will mess up a lot of my code! :(

Comment: I tried calling in playground gives me an error 'Value of type 'Base' has no member 'dynamicType' '

Comment: @Feru Worked fine in Xcode 7.1 beta 3; did they change this at the last minute???

Comment: I assure you that the code I provided compiles and works correctly in 7.1 beta 3. I don't have time right now to download 7.1 final and test again, sorry.

Comment: @Feru Okay, I download and installed the final release Xcode 7.1 and the code I gave you compiles and runs just fine. Of course I have no idea what _you_ are doing, but I assure you if you just copy my code and paste it into an iOS app, it works. (Don't test in a playground. Never use playgrounds. Playgrounds are evil.)

Comment: I tried this again and I could run this in playground. Storing the type information in variable has no issue as well. Awesome. Not sure why this errored initially. Thanks for response. Added a Like to your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93247/discussion-between-feru-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

@matt's answer works with Swift 2.0. In swift 3 you can simply do the following:

```
    class Base {}
    class Derived : Base {}

    var obj: Base = Derived()
    let aClassType = Derived.self

    if type(of: obj) == aClassType {
        print("hey !")
    }
```

Unless === is better. I don't get the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution which doesn't need to create an instance of *saved* type.

The idea is to create a generic struct conforming to protocol **P** with a typealias inside. Then we can create instances of that struct and pass them to a function, which accepts an argument conforming to **P** and has access to a type via typealias in protocol.

Lets create something like this:

```
protocol TypeContainerP {
    typealias type
}

struct TypeContainer<T>: TypeContainerP {
    typealias type = T
}
```

Now we can create instance of TypeContainer parameterized with some types:

```
class A {}
class B {}
let containerA = TypeContainer<A>()
let containerB = TypeContainer<B>()
```

and create function, which has TypeContainerP as an argument and gives us access to type via protocol:

```
func check<T, E: TypeContainerP>(any: T, _: E) {
    print(any is E.type)
}
```

and we have:

```
check(A(), containerA) // true
check(A(), containerB) // false
check(B(), containerA) // false
check(B(), containerB) // true
```